# Заливка диаграммы работает некорректно

Tags: javascript, массивы, push, данные

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка? Должны краситься только те столбцы, высота которых более 200 пикселей, а красятся и те, и с высотой меньше 100 пикселей, хотя я вроде не задавал никаких подобных параметров. Пробовал сделать так, чтобы не красило элементы с высотой меньше 100, но ничего не получилось.
Вот код:

```js
let arr = [];
let addNumber = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

generate.onclick = function () {
  arr.push(addNumber(0, 300));
  data.textContent = arr.join(", ");
};

get_table.onclick = function () {
  let p_table = document.querySelectorAll(".table");

  [].forEach.call(p_table, function (div, v) {
    div.textContent = arr[v];
    div.style.height = arr[v] + "px";
    if (div.style.height >= 200 + 'px') {
      div.classList.add("fill_color");
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.table {
    width: 47px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lime;
}

.fill_color {
    background-color: red;
}

span {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="push_table" id="push_table_1"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="generate">Сгенерировать массив</button>
<button id="get_table">Показать диаграмму</button>
<br>
<br>
<span id="data"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно зачем вы делаете такое

```
div.style.height >= 200 + 'px'
```

когда есть `arr[v]`

```js
let arr = [];
let addNumber = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

generate.onclick = function () {
  arr.push(addNumber(0, 300));
  data.textContent = arr.join(", ");
};

get_table.onclick = function () {
  let p_table = document.querySelectorAll(".table");

  [].forEach.call(p_table, function (div, v) {
    div.textContent = arr[v];
    div.style.height = arr[v] + "px";
    if (arr[v] >= 200) {
      div.classList.add("fill_color");
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.table {
    width: 47px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lime;
}

.fill_color {
    background-color: red;
}

span {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="push_table" id="push_table_1"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="generate">Сгенерировать массив</button>
<button id="get_table">Показать диаграмму</button>
<br>
<br>
<span id="data"></span>
```

Comment: Ну я думал что таким образом идёт сравнение значения, как например style.color = 'red' и т. п. значения из CSS, но потом уже дошло до меня что сравнивается и значение, и  строка, и поэтому код работает некорректно.
Спасибо за помощь! :)

Comment: @AntAnt если ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный

Comment: отметил, только я здесь новый участник, и оценка к сожалению публично не отображается :(

Comment: @AntAnt там галочка под стрелками возле ответа ее можно нажать и принять ответ